# How download expansion file associated with a different app?

Tags: android, download, apk-expansion-files

I have multiple apps and I want users to be able to get the expansion file of one app, from another.  I know how to provide it the correct public key, but what else needs to be done to pull this off?  Has anyone tried such a thing?  My apps use the same shared user id, if that helps at all.  My code looks very similar to the google example expansion file downloader app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the other apps have a service that could be called to download their own expansion file and return the path.